# Chrome extension JS does not run on back button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394237/chrome-extension-not-running-on-back-button).

I am currently developing a chrome extension. This extension is fairly simple, just adding some CSS and JS through a content script:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"], 
      "js": ["jquery-1.12.1.min.js","ducttape.js"],
      "css" : ["orangeisthenewred.css"]
    }
```

And it works great! On first load. However, if the user presses back to return to the page, all the JS stalwartly refuses to run, no matter what I do. Any ideas on how to get this running on a press of the back button?

Edit: This appears to be specific to the back button itself somehow, on further experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can using [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) event to check when users back to the previous page. And if it happens, then you can inject your content script to the page by using [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) method and your CSS file by using [chrome.tabs.insertCSS](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS) method.